# How to detect that line coordinate generate straight line using js?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, charts

I have one problem state in which I want to detect that drawn line is straight or not using co-ordinate calculation.

For example :
coordinate[i] = [X, Y]

coordinate Array like this : [
[1,2],
[2,3],
[3,4],
[5,6],
[6,7],
]

output should be : true. line using this co-ordinate will be straight

My coordinate can change according to Input data by database. I need a algorithm through which I can detect that line will be straighten or not.

Please help me to figure it out.

Comment: Can you not convert two points from the array into an line equation and then check if the rest of the points satisfy that equation or not?

Comment: Thanks For Idea Buddy. I will try this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate slop for each two coordinates/points from array and if the slop is equal, the line is straight.

Formula To calculate slope of 2 coordinates/points :-
Slope of coordinates/points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) is,

```
m = (y2–y1) / (x2–x1);
```

This link may help you :
https://technotip.com/7151/c-program-to-check-if-three-points-are-on-one-straight-line/

Comment: This is helpfull for me. you saved my lot's of hour. Thanks